# Import error:No module named app1.models

Tags: django, python-2.7

In django, I am trying to populate my database from a csv file. with the help of [this](http://mitchfournier.com/2011/10/11/how-to-import-a-csv-or-tsv-file-into-a-django-model/) tutorial I wrote this code:

load_data.py:

```
# Full path and name to your csv file
csv_filepathname="Home/Desktop/MyProject/practice/app1/data/link1.csv"
# Full path to your django project directory
your_djangoproject_home="Home/Desktop/MyProject/practice/"

import sys,os
sys.path.append('Home/Desktop/MyProject/practice/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from app1.models import Link

import csv
dataReader = csv.reader(open(csv_filepathname), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for row in dataReader:
    abc = Link()
    abc.name = row[0]
    abc.roll = row[1]
    abc.save()
```

Now, when I run this, I get import error saying no module named app1.models. I can't figure it out. Can someone please highlight the mistakes?
[my directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQOaI.png)

I'm working on python 2.7 and django 1.6.

Comment: Do you have an app called app1?

Comment: yes, i do have it

Comment: Please show your full directory structure.

Comment: app1 contains data folder which in turn contains load_data.py file and csv file

Comment: #Daniel, I have added my directory structure

Answer (score 0):

All package directories in Python need an `__init__.py` file, which can be empty.

You shouldn't really create app directories yourself anyway; you should have run `manage.py startapp app1` which would have done it for you.

(Also, note you should absolutely not be using Django 1.6, which is several years old, unsupported, and almost definitely insecure. Upgrade to a more recent, supported, version.)

Comment: i created data folder manually. app1 was created using the above command. i only showed the main files that are being used here.